# Incrementing id field in array in mongo using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to auto increment `id` in mongoDb using java. I am completely new to this.
mongo db

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a703d8154c19cbcd1b8caa6"),
    "name" : "bank_account",
    "params" : [ 
        {
            "id":1,
            "key" : null,
            "variable" : "@var"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to increment id in params array.

```
 public static void create(){ 
    DB db = dbClntConn.getDB("dbname");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collectionname");
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject params = new BasicDBObject();
     List<BasicDBObject> doc1=new ArrayList<>();

                    params.put("key",metadataConfig.get("key"));
                    params.put("variable",variable);
                    doc1.add(params);
                    document.put("params",doc1);



                 collection.insert(document);


                       }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use auto-increment in a nosql context ? It's a terrible idea but if you really want to do this, just follow this link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm

Comment: can you please explain why is this a terrible idea?

Comment: If multiple MongoDB instances have to write data at the exactly same moment. How this gonna works ? (clue: it doesn't work and two entities can share same id)